# How can I set up a secure virus laboratory?

Tags: virus, virtualization

I've been playing around with virtual operating systems for some time and began wondering: would it be possible to set up a virus laboratory in a virtual machine?

If not, are there other ways that do not require me to go out and get an additional computer?

Answer (score 0):

The virtualization software and even the hardware can contain all kinds of bugs that would allow a guest program to access the host. There are already known malware that detects VMs and some may be able to use these vulnerabilities.

Also don't bother about dual-booting or changing disks as virus/rootkits that attack BIOS are not even new.

The only secure solution is to use a physically separated computer with an air gap.